# Do the semantics of a project in bytecode change when changing all of its access modifiers to public?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, semantics, access-modifiers

Assuming I have a run-able jar (A.jar) with .class files inside. I also have another run-able jar (B.jar) which is the same with A.jar except for the access modifiers that are all changed to public (for both fields and methods). Is there a chance that some of the semantics are changed? Will it (B.jar) work exactly the same way as the previous one (A.jar)? What are the dangers?

EDIT EXAMPLE: 
A.jar contains bytecode (.class files). I parse it with the asm library and change all of its modifiers to public. The resulting jar is the B.jar file.

Comment: A.jar contains bytecode (.class files). I parse it for example with the asm library and change all of its modifiers to public. The resulting jar is the B.jar file. (It also contains .class files)

Comment: Well, one thing that would break is reflective code that expects an `IllegalAccessError` to happen, because it is not thrown anymore. Also, the results of reflective code that lists constructs with certain modifiers would change.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to statically inline certain callSites and without changing the access modifiers to public some inlines will fail and throw illegal acces when running the modified jar

Answer (score 2):

One possible behavior change is that private methods cannot override methods in a superclass. Which means that changing the subclass method to public could potentially change the method that is invoked at runtime from virtual calls.

From the JVM Spec v11 5.4.5

> An instance method mC can override another instance method mA iff all
>   of the following are true:
>
> mC has the same name and descriptor as mA.
>
> mC is not marked ACC_PRIVATE.
>
> One of the following is true:
>
> mA is marked ACC_PUBLIC.
>
> mA is marked ACC_PROTECTED.
>
> mA is marked neither ACC_PUBLIC nor ACC_PROTECTED nor ACC_PRIVATE, and
>   either (a) the declaration of mA appears in the same run-time package
>   as the declaration of mC, or (b) if mA is declared in a class A and mC
>   is declared in a class C, then there exists a method mB declared in a
>   class B such that C is a subclass of B and B is a subclass of A and mC
>   can override mB and mB can override mA.

Comment: Aren't private methods invoked with InvokeSpecial though? Which means that the modified jar will still be calling these methods with invokeSpecial - The dynamic type of the receiver will still won't matter and the public accessor won't make a difference

Comment: Hmm, B extends A. A a = new B(); a.foo(); if there is also a private B::foo and is changed to public it will be called in the example above.

edit: This also is invalid, because javac won't allow do define a private B::foo in the first place
(attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public)

Comment: `private` methods are invoked via `invokespecial`, but package-private methods are not. So when you have two package-private methods with identical signatures in the class hierarchy but in different packages, they do not override each other. When you turn them to `public`, they do. Further, `invokespecial` only works the intended way when referencing a method within the same class. When you do inlining, as you stated in a comment, that won’t work anyway.

Comment: Indeed, I've already discarded certain inlines that include invokeSpecial. Now I need to do the same with the access modifiers. The example you provide seems to be one scenario I need to take care of. Holger always coming to the rescue! :) +1

Comment: Also, since Java 11, private methods are invoked via invokevirtual.